# swank server *swank-debugger-condition*

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, swank

I am new to Lisp, and working in Emacs with Slime, I am constantly getting this error

```
Error: The variable SWANK/SBCL::*SWANK-DEBUGGER-CONDITION* is unbound.
```

I have spent a long time googling this and can find no reference to that variable. What is it? And what is it supposed to be bound to?

Comment: `SWANK::*SWANK-DEBUGGER-CONDITION*` should be a special variable that holds the condition object currently being debugged, or `NIL` if the debugger is not open. `SWANK/SBCL::*SWANK-DEBUGGER-CONDITION*` appears to be an unbound symbol that shouldn't be used for anything. There must be something wrong with your configuration if it's giving errors about it. Try clearing any custom settings you have. Did you install SBCL and Slime from your os package manager?

Comment: I installed SBCL via the OS package manager, and Slime via the EMACS package manager

Comment: Is there any more information about where this error is coming from?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard well I did try running the sbcl in a VM on the dedicated linux box. Running it directly on the linux box allowed slime to connect to the remote lisp, but running it in a VM on the linux box did not. I have a hunch that the problem might lie with virtual box. I will test it out with Parallels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that is an issue with your version of slime:

https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/320

SO use the late slime confi [with](https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-slime-helper)

> Quicklisp-slime-helper makes it easy to use SLIME from Quicklisp.
>
> To use it, load quicklisp in your Common Lisp implementation, then
>   evaluate:
>
> (ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")
>
> That command will create a file in the Quicklisp base directory called
>   "slime-helper.el". Loading that file will add the Quicklisp slime path
>   to your Emacs load-path.
>
> In your ~/.emacs, you could have something like this:
>
> (load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))   (setq
>   inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
>
> quicklisp-slime-helper is available under the MIT license; see
>   LICENSE.txt for details.